# JQueryUI modal - focus on close button - How to remove focus on close button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

[image: Please find the screen shot]
When using the JQueryUI modal dialog, the close button is automatically focused leading the title exposed through the jquery tooltip. I want nothing in the modal to be focused. I have tried to add a click trigger on the title of the modal window, but it seems that it had no effect.

Please help me.

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {  
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     width : 710,
  height : 410,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,  
  draggable: false
 
    });   
  });
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
 }
 
 iframe {

position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -170px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -340px;
}
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal"></div>
<div id="dialog"  title=" ">
  <iframe style="position:absolute;Left:150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html" ></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your popup.html src?

Comment: You Can use any html page instead of popUp.html

Comment: @NarendrakumarM the html popUp.html doesn't matter..

Comment: Yes. I know that. that's why I am not posting it here.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these solutions worked for me. I found this jsfiddle in the wild that fixed it.

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true,

    // When the dialog is opened, move the focus off the button. This
    // causes the close button to trigger a click event when the space
    // key is pressed.
    open: function( e, ui ) {
        $( this ).siblings( ".ui-dialog-titlebar" )
                 .find( "button" ).blur(); 
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/ekaW6/

Comment: Just here to say, 5 years later, at this is the solution that worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

To unfocus element (`button`, `input` etc) you can use `blur` function (https://api.jquery.com/blur/).

I was fixed your snippet.

```js
$(function() {  
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    width : 310,
    height : 210,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,  
    draggable: false
  });   
  
  /* This is the trick
  * do the blur and remove the hendler from the focus event 
  */
  unBlur();
  $('body').click(unBlur);
  $('.ui-button').off('focus');
});

function unBlur() {
  $('.ui-button').blur();  
}
```

```css
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
}
 
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -170px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -340px;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  outline:none !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 

<div class="modal"></div>
<div id="dialog"  title=" ">
  <iframe style="position:absolute;Left:150" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But if I clicks on outside popup(grayed area) again I am getting focus on close button(blue line around close button in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of JQuery UI Dialog, the focus is set after opening in the dialog this way:

> **Focus**
>
> Upon opening a dialog, focus is automatically moved to the first
>   item that matches the following:
>
> 1. The first element within the dialog with the autofocus attribute
> 2. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's content
> 3. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's buttonpane
> 4. The dialog's close button
> 5. The dialog itself

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-focus

The problem comes from JQuery UI Tooltip. By default, Tooltip are displayed on `mouseover` **and `focusin`**.

If you don't have anything else focusable in your dialog, it goes to point 4 and focus the close button, what leads to show the tooltip.

You should adapt the way your are configuring the tooltips, so that the close button has no tooltip, or that it does not show a tooltip on focus.

I consider not optimal to show tooltip on focus, I disabled the focus for tooltip this way:

```
jQuery(document).tooltip({
    items: "[title]:hover"
});
```

Of course, you probably have to adapt the code for the way you create the tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input with auto focus

```
<input type="hidden" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

or  add

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({
open: function(event,ui) {
    $(this).parent().focus();
}
```

});